# How can I update the html values from the controller in AngularJS, when they change?

Tags: angularjs, setinterval, watch

I'd like to update the html values, any second, from the controller (or service) but I didn't understand why the $watch doesn't work as aspected. Why when the update fn is called $watch doesn't see the changes?

html:

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="BitWatch as bw">

    <p>{{bw.watch.hours}}</p>
    <p>{{bw.watch.mins}}</p>
    <p>{{bw.watch.secs}}</p>

</div>
</body>
```

js:

```
angular.module("app", [])
       .controller("BitWatch", ["$scope", BitWatch])
       .service("bitTime", bitTime);


function BitWatch($scope){
    var self = this;
    self.watch = new bitTime();
    $scope.secs = self.watch.secs;
    setInterval(function(){ self.watch.update(); $scope.secs = self.watch.secs; console.log(self.watch.secs, $scope.secs);}, 3000);
    $scope.$watch( "secs", function(){ self.watch.update(); $scope.secs = self.watch.secs; console.log("chaged", self.watch.secs, $scope.secs); } );

}


function bitTime(){
    var date = new Date();
    var self = this;

    var hours = date.getHours().toString(2);
    self.hours = hours.length<4 ? "0000".substr(hours.length)+hours : hours;

    var mins = date.getMinutes().toString(2);
    self.mins = mins.length<6 ? "000000".substr(mins.length)+mins : mins;

    var secs = date.getSeconds().toString(2);
    self.secs = secs.length<6 ? "000000".substr(secs.length)+secs : secs;

    self.update = function(){
        var date_updated = new Date();

        hours = date_updated.getHours().toString(2);
        self.hours = hours.length<4 ? "0000".substr(hours.length)+hours : hours;

        var mins = date_updated.getMinutes().toString(2);
        self.mins = mins.length<6 ? "000000".substr(mins.length)+mins : mins;

        var secs = date_updated.getSeconds().toString(2);
        self.secs = secs.length<6 ? "000000".substr(secs.length)+secs : secs;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the changes to the scope aren't applied when you use setInterval. 
Use `$interval` instead. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: Can you help me to undertand how to use it?